# Is there any way I can make a connectTodb() function using jstl?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jstl

Is there any way I could use jstl inside a java function? Basically, what I want is I would just call the connectTodb() function in a jsp page where I need a connection. However, I do not know how.

Can I do this for example?

```
    connectTodo() {
       <sql:setDataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name"
                   var="localSource" 
                   user="database_user"  
                   password="database_password"/>
    }
```

How do I call this method in my jsp file? Or if I can't do this, how do I connect to the database with just a function? Help me out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write functions in JSP, but that is generally discouraged. Normally you would create tags and/or fragments. You posted one,

```
<sql:setDataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name"
    var="localSource" 
    user="database_user"  
    password="database_password"/>
```

That is made available in a jsp with the `<%@ %>` block like

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<html>
```

You could write your own tag file like `initDB.tag`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="db" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<sql:setDataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name"
    var="localSource" 
    user="database_user"  
    password="database_password"/>
```

and then you can use it like

```
<db:initDB />
```

Finally, you might check if your server has a connection pool that you can access from a JNDI name.

Comment: hi, a few more questions regarding the answer. if i have created my custom tag file, and then use it as stated above, will a be able to use the var="localsource" in a separate tag? For example if I have a query, <sql:query dataSource="${localSource}" var="result">, would it work?